# What is the IIS metabase.xml?

Tags: windows, iis

In Microsoft Windows, **What is the metabase.xml file?**  Where is it located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is one of two folders that replaced metabase.bin in IIS 6.0. It holds pretty much all of the IIS config information that is not otherwise held in the registry. It is normally at:

*systemroot*\System32\Inetsrv

More info [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a0ea8e51-fb2a-4e80-9d5a-7fe3ae246570.mspx?mfr=true)